# PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, sos

I get following message when I execute "!name2ee app.exe!Program".How can I fix that? 
I am using VS2013.

```
.load sos
extension C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll loaded
!name2ee app.exe!Program
PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have an Internet connection
2. Set "Microsoft Symbol Servers" in Options / Debugging / Symbols

[image: VS Symbols]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have done that settings already and my machine is connected to internet.Later I found from module window that pdb were not downloaded for CLR into framework folder however they were there in my temp folder.I copied them manually to framework folder and the error had gone.However I face different issue now.When I execute "!name2ee app.exe!Program", nothing shows up.However some sos commands work.

Comment: Here is what I get now:                                                                                                          !name2ee app.exe!Program
                                                  //no output
  !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x23c0 (9152)
Child SP       IP Call Site
002DED8C 00550073 JitDemo2.Program.Main(System.String[])
002DEF54 72363DE2 [GCFrame: 002def54]

Comment: What about `!name2ee app.exe!*Program*`?